# PDO: Database connection on remote website

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is an example of the database connection I'm using with my PDO queries:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=some_db;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
 PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
 PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);

$pdo = new PDO($dsn,'Username','Password', $opt);
```

How would I modify it if my database is located on www.mysite.com and I want to access the database from a different website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open up port 3306 to accept connections.

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=mysite.com;dbname=some_db;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
 PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
 PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);

$pdo = new PDO($dsn,'Username','Password', $opt);
```

Comment: Oh, I see - just replacer localhost with a domain name. How do you open up port 3306, though? Is that something you can with phpMyAdmin, or do I need to ask my webhost to do that for me?

Comment: If you have root access, you can do it yourself. go to a shell. and type `nmap mysite.com` and look for the `mysql 3306`

Comment: One more tip - you might be able to do it via a CPanel. I vaguely remember experimenting with remote database connections years ago. I was exploring my CPanel when I clicked on an icon labeled Remote Host Access, or something like that. It looks like you just have to type in a domain name; I see several listed that I must have4 registered previously. I'll test it when I get things sorted out here...